# What does the @ symbol mean in a file's permission settings?

Tags: mac-osx, permissions, console, chmod

I'm on MacOSX, I did `ln -s` on a directory and these are the results:

```
-rwxrwxr-x@ 1 shiki  admin   970332 Mar  6 16:38 apc.so
-rwxrwxr-x@ 1 shiki  admin   653884 Mar  6 16:38 eaccelerator.so
-rw-rw-r--@ 1 shiki  admin    60064 Mar  6 16:38 gettext.a
-rwxrwxr-x@ 1 shiki  admin    80320 Mar  6 16:38 gettext.so
-rw-rw-r--@ 1 shiki  admin   514784 Mar  6 16:38 imap.a
-rwxrwxr-x@ 1 shiki  admin  3886132 Mar  6 16:38 imap.so
```

What do those **@** symbols mean?

Comment: See also: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/42177/what-does-signify-in-unix-file-permissions

Answer (score 63, accepted):

@ signifies that the file has extended attributes.  Those attributes are usually used to signify that the file came from a package, was downloaded from the internet, etc.

```
ls -al@ imap.a
```

will show you the extended attributes that are saved for that file.

Comment: handy followup when you want to remove them: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4833052/how-do-i-remove-the-extended-attributes-on-a-file-in-mac-os-x